# Unable to resolve against local DNS server

Tags: dns, bind, systemd-resolved

I have a Bind9 server set up on my local server (at 192.168.0.15, named "groth") and I've just built a Ubuntu 20.04 laptop (jedi-u20) which I'm trying to set up to query the Bind server.

On the Bind server, in named.conf.local, I have:

```
zone "banksworth.local" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.banksworth";
};
```

and in db.banksworth, I have:

```
    $TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA groth.banksworth.local. admin.banksworth.site. (
    2021120701  ; Serial
    604800      ; Refresh
    86400       ; Retry
    2419200     ; Expire
    604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
    IN  NS  localhost.
    IN  NS  groth.banksworth.local.
    groth   IN  A   192.168.0.15
```

On my Ubuntu laptop, I *think* have the DNS server configured according to `resolvectl status` where it shows 192.168.0.15 under "Global", but only shows 192.168.0.1 (my router) under "Link 4 (wlp3s0)".

If I dig the host, it doesn't resolve, but if I specify a resolver in the dig command, it does:

```
root@jedi-u20:/etc/systemd/network# dig -t a groth.banksworth +short
root@jedi-u20:/etc/systemd/network# dig -t a groth.banksworth +short @192.168.0.15
192.168.0.15
```

I'm sure I'm setting this up wrong. I haven't really had to touch DNS since before Systemd, when you just put a nameserver line in resolv.conf, but I can't get a good handle on how this all hooks together in the new world.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or tell me where I've misunderstood and messed it up, please? Thanks!

Edit: Here's the .network file that I *think* is relevant:

```
root@jedi-u20:/etc/systemd/network# cat /usr/lib/systemd/network/80-wifi-adhoc.network
[Match]
Type=wifi
WLANInterfaceType=ad-hoc

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
```

Comment: Please show your `.network` file used for the link (`wlp3s0`). Most likely you want to set `UseDNS=no` and `DNS=192.168.0.15` in it.

Comment: @TomYan I added the one I think is right. I did a `locate *.network`, and excluding files in snaps, I have:
/usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network
/usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-ve.network
/usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-vz.network
/usr/lib/systemd/network/80-wifi-adhoc.network

Comment: Hmm, how exactly did you configured your WiFi connection? It doesn't seem like you are using networkd as the DHCP client. In that case things might be tricky, since you'll need to make it run `resolvconf` with your desired DNS address instead of what's given by the DHCP server.

Comment: I added my wireless network during the OS install process, and it Just Worked, so it should just be whatever is the default on 20.04. My DHCP server is on the router, separate to the DNS server, which I imagine is a fairly common setup.

Comment: I suppose you can simply try to locate the "WiFi icon" and see if left/right clicking it can lead you to some configuration page where you can opt to use a DNS server statically set instead. It might eventually cause resolved to set the link DNS server to what you set (and only what you set).